# Can Core Data use Google Docs as a persistence store?

Tags: core-data, ios

I'm quite new at Core Data/Cocoa programming, so please bear with me ...

Is it possible to create a custom NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's that
uses Google's GData API: Elements, Entries, Feeds, etc? Tickets could
be used to model -save operations (I think)

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but not directly. The best way to approach it would be to implement a controller that deals with the Google API calls and passes the response/data received on to a managed object model (and vice-versa). The tricky bit will be making sure both sides are always in sync.

Comment: Yes. Core Data is not meant to be used through a network (which usually have high latency), and thus you should handle saving/loading from GData by yourself.